# Trouble with startActivity() in file observers onEvent()

Tags: java, android, fileobserver

I've got a fileObserver running and now I need to start an activity after the onEvent gets called and I'm not quite sure how to do it considering I can't get startActivity().

Here's my current code:

```
public class snapObserver extends FileObserver {

public final String TAG = "DEBUG";
public static Context mContext;

public snapObserver(String path) {
    super(path, FileObserver.CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
    if (path == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "path is null");
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "File created!!!!");
    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, editActivity.class));
}
}
```

This code throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null
>   object reference
>               at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:77)
>               at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:3996)
>               at com.samplersnapshoot.domiq.samplersnapshoot.snapObserver.onEvent(snapObserver.java:28)
>               at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.onEvent(FileObserver.java:122)
>               at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.observe(Native Method)
>               at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.run(FileObserver.java:85)

I have a service running in the background that calls the fileObserver with a simple startWatching.

Comment: @Blackbelt I know but how could I set it considering fileObserver is outside context

Comment: you could another parameter to the constructor. `Service` is also a `Context`

Comment: @Blackbelt thanks, that solved it. Do you wanna create an answer for experience on stack? Or should I just answer it?

Comment: you can answer it, if you want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
public class snapObserver extends FileObserer {
    private Context mContext;

    //any code

    public snapObserver(String path, Context context) {
        super(path, FileObserver.CREATE);

        this.mContext = context;
    }

    //any code
}
```